# How to grid a matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have created a 9500 by 300000 matrix and would wish to know if there is a way to grid it, as I am not sure if a matrix is already gridded. This is actually a velocity matrix for seismic processing. I am new to python and programing please permit the question if it is not tech.

```
mat_vel = np.ones((9500, 306240))
for shotpoint in range(306240): #total shotpoint extracted from the seismic data
    count6 = 0
    count7 = 0
    count1 = 0 # count for totaltime in sesimc data
    count2 = 0
    count3 = 0
    count4 = 0
    totaltime = [0]
    modelvel = [1500]
    vel = 1500
    while totaltime[count1] <= 19.0:
        mat_vel[count6][count8] *= modelvel[count7]
        num = totaltime[count1] + 0.002
        totaltime.append(num)
        modelvel.append(vel)
        count1 += 1
        count6 += 1
        count7 += 1
        if totaltime[count1] >= depth_time[count5] and totaltime[count1] <= (depth_time[count5] + (2*2000/1500)):
            vel = vel1(1)[count2]
            count2 += 1
        elif totaltime[count1] >= (depth_time[count5] + (2*2000/1500))  and totaltime[count1] <= (depth_time[count5] + (2*2000/1500) + (2*4000/1500)):
            vel = vel2(2)[count3]
            count3 += 1
```

Above is part of my code and I used a numpy array. I am just wondering if I would need to grid the velocity matrix to use it on a seismic processing software like SU

Comment: Could you explain what mean to grid a matrix?  Also, if you could include in the question some code It would be very helpful to understand what your are looking for, for example which Python library do you use, is it Numpy?

Comment: I know to create a surface you need a grid but I am not so sure if this is applicable for a velocity plot along shot and time. Also the software I am using expects the velocity file as gridded binary file in GMT or segy format.

Comment: How you imported the data in Python? Could you not use the same method to export it back to the software?  ( I am trying to guess what `mat_vel` is: is it the ground velocity as a function of time and depth for a specific location? )

Comment: mat_vel is the genrated velocity matrix; it is interval velocity of a location as a function of shot points and time(depth). I imported the data as a text file and can export the matrix (mat_vel) as a text. What I am askng is how to put it in a grid format, if it is not already, using python or GMT.

Comment: I don't think the array is already in a "grid format" , it's just an array of numbers without any included information about what the data is about (units, spacing between points...etc),  Maybe you could look at Python libraries dealing with segy file format, I found for example https://segyio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ , https://github.com/sixty-north/segpy and  https://github.com/Statoil/segyio . Is this the grid format your are using: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esri_grid ?  I am not working in the field, but I am not sure a grid format is something uniquely defined and standard

Comment: –@xdze2 you're right. It was just an array without any information. I did grid it using netCDF4 in python and it come out just the way it should. Thanks